# How to combine if/else statement

Tags: java

Basically this program roles a dice between a computer and then shows who got the higher score. So in my last if/else statement, the main difference is you won, vs you lost. Is there anyway that I can combine this so it's cleaner? I tried combining it but couldn't figure it out. Any ideas? Appreciate it!!

```
//import scanner and random
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

//declare variables and methods
class Main {
int userOne, userTwo, compOne, compTwo, userTotal, compTotal;
char playAgain;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random gen = new Random();

  //method to run entire program
  public void runProgram()
  {
    int r=1;
    //this will run the roll of the dice for the user and the computer
    for(r=1; r<2;)
    {
    System.out.println("Your turn:");
    userOne = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("Your first roll was: " + userOne);
    userTwo = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("Your second roll was: " + userTwo);
    userTotal = userOne + userTwo;
    System.out.println("Your total of the two rolls was: " + userTotal);

    System.out.println("Computers turn:");
    compOne = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("The computers first roll was: " + compOne);
    compTwo = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("The computers second roll was: " + compTwo);
    compTotal = compOne + compTwo;
    System.out.println("The computers total of the two rolls was: " + compTotal);

    //This determines win or loss and lets the user choose if they want to play again
    if (userTotal > compTotal)
    {
      //winning- statement to ask if the user wants to play again
      System.out.println("You won! Would you like to play again? Respond with Yes or No: ");
      playAgain = scan.next().charAt(0);
      if ((String.valueOf(playAgain)).equalsIgnoreCase("y") == true)
      {
        r=1;
      }
      else
      {
        r=2;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //losing- statement to ask if the user wants to play again
      System.out.println("Sorry, you lost. Would you like to play again? Yes or No?");
      playAgain = scan.next().charAt(0);

      if ((String.valueOf(playAgain)).equalsIgnoreCase("y") == true)
      {
        r=1;
      }
      else
      {
        r=2;
      }
    }
    }
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main prog = new Main();
    prog.runProgram();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move all the stuff that's in both branches to after the else-block?

Comment: And instead of `r` just use `while (true)`, and `break` when they don't want to play again.

Answer (score 1):

Like khelwood suggested, you can combine the play again messages outside of the win/loss if statement.

```
if (userTotal > compTotal) {
    System.out.println("You won!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you lost.");
}

System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes or No?");
playAgain = scan.next().charAt(0);

if ((String.valueOf(playAgain)).equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    r = 1;
} else {
    r = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by moving the code responsible for determining whether or not to run the program again outside the if/else statement since it doesn't matter if the user won or lost, in the end, the question remains the same: do you want to play again or not? regardless of the result, therefore such logic should not be encapsulated by the logic responsible for determining who one (because again, irrelevant).

The second thing and this is totally optional but it will make your code cleaner, it seems you're using if/else statements just to determine which values should be assigned to variables, in such cases, it is cleaner to use the [ternary operator](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-a-ternary-operator-in-java#:%7E:text=The%20ternary%20operator%20is%20a,a%20value%20to%20be%20returned.)

And one more thing, when using methods that return a boolean true/false it is unnecessary to type == false/true since the function itself already does that, such as the equalsIgnoreCase() function.

So after all of these edits, your code looks something like this:

```
    //import scanner and random
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

//declare variables and methods
class Main {
int userOne, userTwo, compOne, compTwo, userTotal, compTotal;
char playAgain;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random gen = new Random();
String result;

  //method to run entire program
  public void runProgram() {
    int r=1;
    //this will run the roll of the dice for the user and the computer
    for(r=1; r<2;)
    {
    System.out.println("Your turn:");
    userOne = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("Your first roll was: " + userOne);
    userTwo = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("Your second roll was: " + userTwo);
    userTotal = userOne + userTwo;
    System.out.println("Your total of the two rolls was: " + userTotal);

    System.out.println("Computers turn:");
    compOne = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("The computers first roll was: " + compOne);
    compTwo = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println("The computers second roll was: " + compTwo);
    compTotal = compOne + compTwo;
    System.out.println("The computers total of the two rolls was: " + compTotal);

    //This determines win or loss and lets the user choose if they want to play again
      result = userTotal > compTotal ?  "won! " :  "lost. ";

      // Ternary operator
      System.out.println("you " + result + "Would you like to play again? Yes or No?");

      playAgain = scan.next().charAt(0);

      // another ternary operator
      r = String.valueOf(playAgain).equalsIgnoreCase("y") ? 1 : 2;

    }
  }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main prog = new Main();
    prog.runProgram();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I would say could be improved with this code is avoiding copying and pasting code. Don't ever repeat yourself.

Second thing to improve is you could make your loop `while((String.valueOf(playAgain)).equalsIgnoreCase("y"))` instead of your weird `for` loop. That way you don't have a confusing r variable that is based on whether or not playAgain is 'y'.

```
  public void runProgram()
  {
    playAgain = 'y';
    //this will run the roll of the dice for the user and the computer
    while ((String.valueOf(playAgain)).equalsIgnoreCase("y") == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Your turn:");
        userOne = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println("Your first roll was: " + userOne);
        userTwo = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println("Your second roll was: " + userTwo);
        userTotal = userOne + userTwo;
        System.out.println("Your total of the two rolls was: " + userTotal);

        System.out.println("Computers turn:");
        compOne = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println("The computers first roll was: " + compOne);
        compTwo = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println("The computers second roll was: " + compTwo);
        compTotal = compOne + compTwo;
        System.out.println("The computers total of the two rolls was: " + compTotal);

        //This determines win or loss and lets the user choose if they want to play again
        if (userTotal > compTotal)
        {
            //winning- statement to ask if the user wants to play again
            System.out.println("You won! Would you like to play again? Respond with Yes or No: ");
        }
        else
        {
            //losing- statement to ask if the user wants to play again
            System.out.println("Sorry, you lost. Would you like to play again? Yes or No?");
        }
          
        playAgain = scan.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Making these changes make your code a little more clear about what you're intending the program to do.

Comment: Please remove the `== true`. `equalsIgnoreCase` already returns a boolean

Comment: @MrCodingB that is true. However, some may say that including the ```== true``` helps with readability.

Comment: Yes but most conventions tell you not to use it, so it's best not to post it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just moves duplicated stuff out of the if-else statement.
Also, `== true` can be removed from `if()` since it already returns a boolean value.

```
if (userTotal > compTotal){
    //winning- statement to ask if the user wants to play again
    System.out.println("You won! Would you like to play again? Respond with Yes or No: ");
}else{
    //losing- statement to ask if the user wants to play again
    System.out.println("Sorry, you lost. Would you like to play again? Yes or No?");
}

playAgain = scan.next().charAt(0);

if ((String.valueOf(playAgain)).equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
    r=1;
}else{
    r=2;
}
```